# Binding Counts to Dataframe using if_else or Count

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've been working on code to add new columns to an existing `tbl_df`.  Add count columns for the values in columns; order_type, food_type, ice_cream_type, and customer_info with some specifics.  I've outlined the specifics I'm looking for within each column below.

The way I see it my 2 choices are: `dplyr::if_else`, or a combination of `dplyr::count` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

One possible solution I thought of was to use `mutate_at` and pass the individual column names with `if_else`, but I'm not sure if that would be the best way to do it.

My solution below uses `tidyr` and `dplyr`.  The code seems like it's way less efficient than it should be.  I'd imagine there's a better solution to do what I'm looking for.

I'm looking to do the following:

1. order_type would only be counts for "phone", and column name would take on the value "phone" with an '_order' after it.  In theory, I'm looking to see how to take a value from a row and add a suffix.  Maybe `glue` or `paste0`?
2. All values for `food_type` but rename "ice cream" to `ice_cream` for the column name
3. Count everything in ice_cream_type, but only create count columns for the non-NA values
4. Only count rows that have "first time" or start with "repeat" within `customer_info` column
5. Join to original `df`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~date, ~Initials, ~order_type,  ~food_type, ~ice_cream_type,    ~customer_info, ~cost,
    "2/1/2020",      "JS",     "phone", "ice cream",       "vanilla", "repeat_multiple",     5,
   "1/15/2019",      "JO",    "online",    "entree",              NA,      "first_time",    20,
  "12/29/2017",      "JE", "in-person",     "snack",              NA,         "no info",   6.5,
    "1/1/2018",      "OI",    "online",     "snack",              NA,    "repeat_first",     2,
    "2/1/2020",      "VM",     "phone",    "entree",              NA,         "no info",    12,
   "1/15/2019",      "PJ",     "phone",     "drink",              NA, "repeat_multiple",     3,
  "12/29/2017",      "JO",    "online",    "entree",              NA,    "repeat_first",    14,
    "1/1/2018",      "EE", "in-person", "ice cream",     "chocolate",      "first_time",     6,
    "2/1/2020",      "SL",    "online",    "entree",              NA,      "first_time",     6
  )


# order_type 
order_type_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Initials) %>% 
  count(order_type) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = order_type, 
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  select(Initials, phone_order = phone)

food_type_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Initials) %>% 
  count(food_type) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = food_type, 
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  rename(ice_cream = "ice cream")

ice_cream_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Initials) %>% 
  count(ice_cream_type) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ice_cream_type, 
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  select(-"NA")

customer_info_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Initials) %>% 
  count(customer_info) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = customer_info, 
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(repeat_customer = repeat_first + repeat_multiple) %>% 
  select(Initials, first_time, repeat_customer)  



desired_df <- df %>% 
  left_join (order_type_df) %>% 
  left_join(food_type_df) %>% 
  left_join(customer_info_df) %>% 
  left_join(ice_cream_df)
#> Joining, by = "Initials"Joining, by = "Initials"Joining, by = "Initials"Joining,
#> by = "Initials"


desired_df 
#> # A tibble: 9 x 16
#>   date  Initials order_type food_type ice_cream_type customer_info  cost
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     <chr>          <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 2/1/~ JS       phone      ice cream vanilla        repeat_multi~   5  
#> 2 1/15~ JO       online     entree    <NA>           first_time     20  
#> 3 12/2~ JE       in-person  snack     <NA>           no info         6.5
#> 4 1/1/~ OI       online     snack     <NA>           repeat_first    2  
#> 5 2/1/~ VM       phone      entree    <NA>           no info        12  
#> 6 1/15~ PJ       phone      drink     <NA>           repeat_multi~   3  
#> 7 12/2~ JO       online     entree    <NA>           repeat_first   14  
#> 8 1/1/~ EE       in-person  ice cream chocolate      first_time      6  
#> 9 2/1/~ SL       online     entree    <NA>           first_time      6  
#> # ... with 9 more variables: phone_order <int>, ice_cream <int>, snack <int>,
#> #   entree <int>, drink <int>, first_time <int>, repeat_customer <int>,
#> #   chocolate <int>, vanilla <int>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the pivoting and multiple `left_join`s, an option may be to use `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>% 
       mutate(new_order = replace(order_type, 
            order_type != 'phone', NA_character_)) %>% 
       unite(coln, new_order, food_type, ice_cream_type, customer_info, sep=";") %>% 
       select(coln) %>%
       cSplit_e("coln", sep=";", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE) %>%
       rename_all(~ str_remove(., "coln_")) %>%
       bind_cols(df, .) %>%
       select(-`NA`)
out[8:ncol(out)]
# A tibble: 9 x 11
#  chocolate drink entree first_time `ice cream` `no info` phone repeat_first repeat_multiple snack vanilla
#      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         0     0      0          0           1         0     1            0               1     0       1
#2         0     0      1          1           0         0     0            0               0     0       0
#3         0     0      0          0           0         1     0            0               0     1       0
#4         0     0      0          0           0         0     0            1               0     1       0
#5         0     0      1          0           0         1     1            0               0     0       0
#6         0     1      0          0           0         0     1            0               1     0       0
#7         0     0      1          0           0         0     0            1               0     0       0
#8         1     0      0          1           1         0     0            0               0     0       0
#9         0     0      1          1           0         0     0            0               0     0       0
```

---

We can also do this with `map` by passing the column names

```
out2 <- map(names(df)[3:6], ~ 
          df %>%
              count(Initials, !! rlang::sym(.x)) %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from = .x, values_from =n,
                 values_fill = list(n = 0))) %>% 
            reduce(full_join, by = 'Initials') %>% 
          select(-`NA`) %>%
          rename_all(~ str_c(., "newcols"))
          bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using mutate_at and passing along columns with if_else?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz If you are thinking about `count`, it won't work with vector input i.e. `mutate_at` it considers each column as a vector

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Can you check my updated code with `map`

Comment: Could we do mutate_at with if_else?  I'm guessing that's not any more efficient since you would have to do the mutate_at to count all values within the column, and then manually remove count columns I don't want?

Comment: I really like both options, thanks!  2 questions on your map.  1. can you also show me how to pass column names instead of column placement.  2. Can I pass along a naming convention?  I know that pivot_wider takes a prefix.  What about suffix, or some other naming convention for the column?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz It takes only `names_prefix` in `pivot_wider`.  If you want to add some new names, it is easier after the before the `bind_cols` i.e. `%>% rename_all(~ str_c(., "newcols")) %>% bind_cols(df, .)`

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Also, another point is that if you want to only subset some values, then `replace` the others to `NA` `map(names(df)[3:6], ~ df %>% count(Initials, !! rlang::sym(.x)) %>% mutate_at(vars(.x), ~ replace(., . %in% c("in-person", "no info"), NA_character_ )) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = .x, values_from =n,
                  values_fill = list(n = 0))) %>%  reduce(full_join, by = 'Initials')`

Comment: Thanks!  Can I pass along column names instead of map(names(df)[3:6]?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Yes, you can do `map(c("order_type",  "food_type"), ~`, it is only that I find it easier to use `names` if you check the `class` both are `character`s

Comment: Is the bind_cols necessary?  I'm getting an error when I run that.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz. what is the error?  Is it due to different length of rows.  In that case, just do a `left_join(df, ., by = 'Initials')`

Comment: Error: Argument 2 must be length 9, not 8  Did you mean left_join instead of full_join in the reduce?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Yess, it would be `full_join` in your orignial data, because here in the example it is working